# JSch "pipe closed" when using SFTP download InputStream after disconnect

Tags: java, sftp, inputstream, jsch

I am using JSch to open a SFTP channel to a remote server. I use the below code to open the connection and download the file:

```
public org.springframework.core.io.Resource download(){
    JSch jsch = new Jsch();
    Session session = jsch.get("root", "192.168.1.10", 22);
    session.setPassword("root");
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
    session.connect();
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channelSftp.connect();
    InputStream is = channelSftp.get("/root/example.mp4");
    channelSftp.exit();
    session.disconnect();
    return new org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource(is);    
}
```

The problem is:

1. If I use `exit()` and/or `disconnect()` method, there will be `Pipe closed` exception thrown
2. If I don't, my method return a `Resource` successfully but the channel/session is still in  `connected` state.

So I have a question for this implementation whether there is something wrong ? If there isn't, will the number of sessions increase till the SFTP server denies or they will be closed at a time in future, how can I handle this ?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the data after you disconnect.

If the API needs `InputStream` and you then lose the control, you can implement a wrapper `InputStream` implementation that delegates all calls to your `is`, and calls `disconnect` once `InputStream.close` is called.

---

Easier but less efficient solution for not-too-large files is to read the JSch stream to memory (to a `byte` array) and return the array or wrapper `ByteArrayInputStream` to your API.

Comment: thank you very much @Martin , since my app is used for downloading small files so I think above solution is acceptable

Answer (score 2):

You must not read from the input stream after disconnect() is called. Either read data first from the stream and then call disconnect(), or use *channelSftp.get(sourceDir, destinationDir)* to download the file to a local destination directory in the local filesystem before you call disconnect().

Comment: actually I use this method for function downloading a file (form remote server) in my web application (spring boot), so how can I push this file to client despite of downloading the file to a local destination directory (like `/temp`) ?

Comment: agreed on this. dont close channelSftp client till you are using this and reading files.